# JavaScript Regex splitting string into words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following Regex

```js
console.log("Test #words 100-200-300".toLowerCase().match(/(?:\B#)?\w+/g))
```

From the above you can see it is splitting "100-200-300". I want it to ignore "-" and keep the word in full as below:

```
--> ["test", "#words", "100-200-300"]
```

I need the Regex to keep the same rules, with the addition of not splitting words connected with "-"

Comment: You could repeat matching `-` and `\w+` like `(?:\B#)?\w+(?:-\w+)*` or without the `\B` like `#?\w+(?:-\w+)*` https://regex101.com/r/YRg5My/1

Comment: Is regex the right solution? Would it be better to use javascript to `split` on a space character: `str.split(" ")`? What do you do in case of `words_separated_by_underscores`?

Comment: I am not sure what the regex does entirely, It is a line of code we are using in an indexing script. It is causing a fault since it splits on "-" i don't want to change what it does just stop it splitting on "-"

Comment: @Thefourthbird could you show me how the entire Regex should look I don't understand what you are suggesting - Thanks.

Comment: @MartinWebb You might shorten the code and omit `.toLowerCase()` as `\w` also matches that. Try `console.log("Test #words 100-200-300".match(/#?\w+(?:-\w+)*/g));` See https://rextester.com/RSVR49477

Comment: @Thefourthbird this seems to work, but i need the .toLowerCase() as I want the results to be affected.

Comment: @Thefourthbird do you want to answer this so I can select it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your current example, you could match an optional `#`, 1+ word chars and repeat 0+ times a part that matches a `#` and 1+ word chars again.

```
#?\w+(?:-\w+)*
```

- `#?` Optional `#`
- `\w+` 1+ word characters
- `(?:-\w+)*` Repeat as a group 0+ times matching `-` and 1+ word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S2ZMDw/1)

```js
console.log("Test #words 100-200-300".toLowerCase().match(/#?\w+(?:-\w+)*/g));
```

About the `\B` [anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (following text taken from the link)

> \B is the negated version of \b. \B matches at every position where \b
>   does not. Effectively, \B matches at any position between two word
>   characters as well as at any position between two non-word characters.

If you do want to use that anchor, see for example some difference in matches [with \B](https://regex101.com/r/CarbKX/1) and [without \B](https://regex101.com/r/PSTNnJ/1)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.